# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dropout_5_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape ()

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm learning deep learning.I'm doing deep learning using keras in python 3.6.For my deep learning task, I have 136 input variables. I have written a custom loss function.Below is the code for loss function

```
import keras.backend as K
def rmsle(y, y0):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.pow(K.log(y)-K.log(y0), 2)))
```

This is the code I used for deep learning

```
model=keras.models.Sequential()    
model.add(Dropout(0.2, input_shape=(136,)))    
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(20,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu',kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))        
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(45,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu',kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(20,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu',kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='tanh',kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.compile(loss=rmsle,optimizer='adam')    
model.fit(input,outpu,epochs=100,shuffle=True,verbose=2)
```

I'm getting error message as

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dropout_5_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape ()
```

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

std_df is my dataframe from which I'm getting input & output. I did following check to see if there is any empty row(/s)

```
np.where(std_df.applymap(lambda x: x == ''))
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: Somehow the input you gave to the network is empty?

Comment: No.I checked the input & it's not empty

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro.I have added the code to check if my data contains any empty.But I couldn't find anything.

Comment: That doesn't help, what is the shape of the input array, the one you give to model.fit ?

Comment: Hi @MatiasValdenegro,shape of my input is (3121, 136)

Comment: I don't think we can keep guessing, you should make a self-contained example that demonstrates your problem, and include it in your question. Else it will be just too many questions trying to debug your problem.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Sorry, I didn't get.What do you mean by self-contained example?I already have given the code I used & the error message what I'm getting in my question. What else you want in self-contained example in my question?

Comment: I cannot run this code and get the same error message as you, you need to provide an example that when anybody runs it, it produces the error.